# Google Sheets Script Auto Sort by 2 Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello if anybody could help I would be extremely grateful.  I am trying to write an auto-sort script for Google Sheets that would sort first by Column D (sort by cell color, order Green, Yellow & Red and then sort by Column C (sort by date).

I have spent countless hours trying to research this.  However, I am unable to find anything about a script for auto-sorting cell color.

[Google Sheet Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdbpd.png)

The code I have as follows:

```
function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:E116");
  range.sort([
{column: 4, ascending: true},  
{column: 3, ascending: true}
]);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

I need to edit command for column 4.  However unsure of what command it is to auto sort cell color.

Comment: Consider adding a code snippet of the piece you are stuck on or create a minimal snippet with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You might try adding and extra column that represents the colors with a number in the order that you want them and then sort them and remove the column afterwards.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but it would work. You could add a numbered prefix to your coloured column values. **1. PREVUE**, **2. Yard**, **3. Rail**. Then you can sort by the value.

Comment: Made edit to the original question.

Comment: 1.`getValues()` 2. `getBackgrounds()`3.  Use ``Array#sort()`` with your own customsort function to sort values by backgrounds/date

Comment: Thank you for all your solutions and suggestions.  I have managed to solve the problem.